# Slicing a matrix: unresolved access of

Tags: chapel

I'm digging into Chapel and I am stuck at slicing a matrix inside a function. The function receiving the matrix is the following:

```
proc outer_function(x: [?DX]) {

    var number_rows: int = x.shape(1);
    var number_columns: int = DX.rank;
    var result: [1..number_columns] real;

    if number_columns == 1 then {
        result[1] = inner_function(x);
    } else {
        var column_domain: domain(1) = {1..number_columns};
        for i in column_domain do {
            result[i] = inner_function(x[1..number_rows, i]);
        }

    }

    return result;
}
```

I.e., the `outer_function` can receive a vector or a matrix. If it receives a vector it calls `inner_function` with the same input parameter. If `outer_function` receives a matrix, then I want to slice the input matrix by columns and call `inner_function`.

The issue is that slicing the input matrix with `x[1..number_rows, i]` or with `x[{1..number_rows}, i]` will throw an error at compile time:

- `x[1..number_rows, i]`: error: unresolved access of '[domain(1,int(64),false)] int(64)' by '[range(int(64),bounded,false), int(64)]'
- `x[{1..number_rows}, i]`: error: unresolved access of '[domain(1,int(64),false)] int(64)' by '[domain(1,int(64),false), int(64)]'

I need help to find out why I am getting this error, and if there's a more Chapel-like way to achieve what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you're getting is due to the fact that your function's `else` branch is trying to slice `x` as though it were a 2D array (since it uses two indexing expressions: `1..number_rows` and `i`) even though some callsites are passing in a 1D array / vector (or so I'm assuming based on your description and error message).  By default, Chapel only supports slicing 1D arrays using a single indexing expression and 2D arrays using two indexing expressions; doing otherwise results in unresolved access errors like the ones you're getting.

I believe the fix is fairly simple:  You want the compiler to fold your function's conditional such that it only considers the `then` branch when `x` is 1D and the `else` branch when `x` is 2D.  Then, the 2D slicing expression will only be evaluated when it is legal.

Chapel folds conditionals whose tests are `param` expressions (meaning that the expression can be evaluated at compile-time).  The rank of an array is a `param` value, so your conditional is very close to being folded except that you stored the rank into a variable (`var number_columns`) and used that in the conditional.  Because the compiler can't generally know the values of variables, the presence of the `var` in the test expression (`number_columns == 1`) disables its ability to fold the conditional (even though you and I can see that the variable is initialized with a `param` and not changed thereafter).

One fix would be to declare `number_columns` to be a `param`:

```
param number_columns: int = DX.rank;
...
if number_columns == 1 then {
```

This will cause the conditional's test to be a `param` expression since (a) `number_columns` is now a `param`, (b) `1` is a `param`, and (c) Chapel supports an implementation of `==` that compares `param int`s and returns a `param bool`. As a result, the expression can now be evaluated at compile-time, and the conditional will be folded such that only the 1D or 2D version will persist for a given 1D or 2D formal `x`.

That said, an even simpler fix would be to simply make the test reason about the rank of `DX` directly:

```
if DX.rank == 1 then {
```

This will cause the conditional to be folded for the same reasons as the previous rewrite.

(And note that this may actually be what you want since presumably `number_columns` ought to be something more like `x.shape(2)` rather than `x`'s rank, which will cause it to always be 1 or 2?).

To that end, here is a proposed rewrite of your code with illustrative calls and a proposed `inner_function()` that accepts 1D arrays:

```
config var n = 3;

var v: [1..n] real = -1;
writeln(v);
writeln(outer_function(v));

var D2 = {1..n, 1..n};
var A: [D2] real = [(i,j) in D2] i + j / 10.0;
writeln(A);
writeln(outer_function(A));

proc outer_function(x: [?DX]) {
  var number_rows: int = x.shape(1);
  var number_columns: int = if x.rank == 1 then 1 else x.shape(2);
  var result: [1..number_columns] real;

  if x.rank == 1 then {
    result[1] = inner_function(x);
  } else {
    var column_domain: domain(1) = {1..number_columns};
    for i in column_domain do {
      result[i] = inner_function(x[1..number_rows, i]);
    }
  }

  return result;
}

proc inner_function(x: [?DX]) {
  if x.rank != 1 then
    compilerError("inner_function only accepts 1D arrays");
  return + reduce x;
}
```

Note that my `inner_function()` is similarly relying on folding of conditionals to only generate the compiler error in the event that `inner_function()` is passed an array whose rank is not 1 (try calling `inner_function(A)` to trigger this compiler error).

Assuming I'm on the track that you want, here's an even cleaner (and more flexible) implementation of `outer_function()`:

```
proc outer_function(x: [?DX]) {
  if x.rank == 1 {
    return inner_function(x);
  } else {
    var result: [DX.dim(2)] real;
    for i in result.domain do {
      result[i] = inner_function(x[DX.dim(1), i]);
    }
    return result;
  }
}
```

Here, I've done two main things and one minor one:

- taken advantage of the fact that the conditional is going to be folded to have each branch return a different type -- the 1D case will return a scalar and the 2D case will return a 1D array
- used `DX.dim(i)` to refer to the ranges defining the dimensions of `DX` so that this function will work whether `DX` has 1-based indices or 0-based indices (or b-based indices) and preserve those indices in the `result` vector that it creates and returns
- removed the `then` keyword which is not necessary when using curly brackets / a compound statement to define a conditional's body.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation!

Comment: In the final example, the 'for' loop can safely be changed into a 'forall' loop to make it parallel without sacrificing the cleanliness.

Comment: Belatedly: If you're not fond of relying on the folding of param conditionals, another option for writing this pattern would be to have two overloads of outer_function() and to guard them by 'where (x.rank == 1)' and 'where (x.rank == 2)' such that the compiler would call the appropriate one based on the array argument's rank.